# SQL SentryOne Plan Explorer, What is Duration?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-execution-plan, sql-tuning

I've just started using the SentryOne Plan Explorer to help tune my SQL Server queries, and have a question, I can't seem to find an answer for. What is Duration? 
I would think it's the total time it took for the query to run. However, every query I am testing goes much longer in real-time than what ends up showing under Duration.

Below is a screenshot of what I'm seeing. Watching the query run takes over 2 minutes, but the final duration ends up being .770?

Thanks for any insight!

[image: duration]

Comment: Why don't you check with SentryOne? Their documentation should explain their output. This question is out of scope for SO.

Comment: While a query is running, we show clock time on the status bar. However, at the end, we sum up the total duration, in milliseconds, as reported by *the trace rows we collected*. We subtract duration from any trace rows that are discarded (e.g. events that don't generate plans, like WAITFOR). If you send your .pesession file to community@sentryone.com we can help you take a closer look.

Comment: And I agree with @SeanLange, this isn't a peer programming question, this is a product support question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I posted and uploaded my plan here: https://answers.sqlperformance.com/questions/4879/clock-time-is-over-2-minutes-but-duration-is-684-a.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer provided by SentryOne:

While a query is running, we show clock time on the status bar. However, at the end, we sum up the total duration, in milliseconds, as reported by the trace rows we collected. We subtract duration from any trace rows that are discarded (e.g. events that don't generate plans, like WAITFOR).